# koRpus package utilising TreeTagger within R (RStudio) on macOS

Tags: r, macos-high-sierra, treetagger, korpus

im exploring the koRpus package in R on macOS, in trying to use the *treetag* function on the following object:

> text
>   [1] "Because I could not stop for Death -"   "He kindly stopped for me -"
>   [3] "The Carriage held but just Ourselves -" "and Immortality"

using the following syntax

`> tagged.text <- treetag(as.vector(paste(text, collapse = '')), format = "obj", debug = TRUE)`

i get the following error

> ```
>   file:  /var/folders/bt/sdf_vz6d3qbd188c7tkz50gw0000gn/T//RtmpoatWov/tempTextFromObject12d3d169614b6.txt
>
>
>
>     sys.tt.call:  /Applications/treetagger/cmd/tree-tagger-english /var/folders/bt/sdf_vz6d3qbd188c7tkz50gw0000gn/T//RtmpoatWov/tempTextFromObject12d3d169614b6.txt
> ```

Error in **matrix(unlist(strsplit(tagged.text, "\t"))**, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

when i try the emboldened command above on its equivalent, i get this

> matrix(unlist(strsplit(paste(text, collapse = ''), "\t")))
>        [,1]                                                                                                                  [1,] "Because I could not stop for Death -He kindly stopped for me
>   -The Carriage held but just Ourselves -and Immortality"

my workspace is as follows

> > sessionInfo() R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit) Running under: macOS High Sierra
> >     10.13.1
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
>   LAPACK:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] quanteda_0.99.12    koRpus_0.10-2
>   data.table_1.10.4-3 scales_0.5.0         [5] purrr_0.2.4
>   readr_1.1.1         tidyr_0.7.2         tibble_1.3.4         [9]
>   tidyverse_1.1.1     gutenbergr_0.1.3    ggplot2_2.2.1
>   stringr_1.2.0       [13] dplyr_0.7.4         janeaustenr_0.1.5
>   tidytext_0.1.4
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] reshape2_1.4.2
>   haven_1.1.0         lattice_0.20-35     colorspace_1.3-2     [5]
>   htmltools_0.3.6     SnowballC_0.5.1     yaml_2.1.14
>   rlang_0.1.2          [9] foreign_0.8-69      glue_1.2.0
>   modelr_0.1.1        readxl_1.0.0        [13] bindrcpp_0.2
>   bindr_0.1           plyr_1.8.4          munsell_0.4.3       [17]
>   gtable_0.2.0        cellranger_1.1.0    rvest_0.3.2
>   psych_1.7.8         [21] evaluate_0.10.1     knitr_1.17
>   forcats_0.2.0       parallel_3.4.2      [25] broom_0.4.2
>   tokenizers_0.1.4    Rcpp_0.12.13        backports_1.1.1     [29]
>   RcppParallel_4.3.20 jsonlite_1.5        fastmatch_1.1-0
>   mnormt_1.5-5        [33] hms_0.3             digest_0.6.12
>   stringi_1.1.5       bookdown_0.5        [37] grid_3.4.2
>   rprojroot_1.2       tools_3.4.2         magrittr_1.5        [41]
>   lazyeval_0.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.1     Matrix_1.2-11       xml2_1.1.1
>   [45] lubridate_1.7.1     assertthat_0.2.0    rmarkdown_1.6
>   httr_1.3.1          [49] R6_2.2.2            nlme_3.1-131
>   compiler_3.4.2